# Conditionally scheduling a Task in a Discord bot for a specific time

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to conditionally schedule a message to send using [Tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers) - I currently have a 24 hour loop task which I would like to conditionally create/trigger a separate Task at a parameterized time.

Not sure if its possible using Tasks alone, seen some suggestions to use cron/some cron library but curious if there is a better way than I have been trying. I've considered maybe using the `change_interval` method to adjust the current loop to run again at the new time if the conditional is met (and using the method again to change it back to its normal 24 hour loop), but this feels like a janky solution if there is a better way.

I tried a method that, when invoked, would essentially make a new task, however I can see how this wouldn't work if the `tasks` wrapper wouldn't behave as I expect within a method - note that this code does not seem to work

```
def schedule_alert(new_time):
    @tasks.loop(time=new_time, count=1)
    def alert():
        ...


@tasks.loop(hours=24, time=notification_time)
def daily_method():
   new_time = some_code()
   if new_time:
       # if this condition is met, I want to schedule a new task at the new_time
       schedule_alert(new_time)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @alec_djinn updated post with example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to run it once, you don't need to use a loop for that. You can simply create a function that sleeps until the given time.
For example:

```py
async def alert(alert_time):
   await discord.utils.sleep_until(alert_time)
   # do something
   ...


@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def daily_method():
   new_time = some_code()
   if new_time:
      asyncio.create_task(alert(new_time))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much! Originally I was trying to use the `schedule` module but this using `asyncio` to create a background task that just waits to send the message works just as I was hoping

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.py 2.0.0 we can schedule tasks with the `tasks.loop` decorator and the `time` parameter:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
from datetime import datetime

#            year, month, day, hour, minute
run_at = datetime(2023, 3, 7, 12, 0)


@tasks.loop(hours=24, time=run_at)
async def my_task():
     print("I run everyday at 12:00")


my_task.start()
```

Comment: so this part i understand, what im trying to do is schedule a new task conditionally (see the updated code)

Comment: well cause you never start the task @zscrub